# struts 2 tables

Tags: web-applications, struts2, datatables

this is my first web application and I need to create a webpage that has a table and data is being filled from the back end database. I also want to include paging in that.

I found these when doing a google on tables and struts2:
Datatable.net and struts2 grid plugin.

are there any better solutions for creating tables?

Comment: a solution is good or bad, depends on your requirement. I do like datatable better, it is very flexible, which also means, that you have to do lots of thing by yourself. struts2-jquery-grid-plugin is also nice, and give a table feel very quickly. what you should do is `DEFINE YOUR REQUIREMENT AND TRY IT OUT`, whatever which solution you are picking..

Comment: `struts2 grid plugin`,`custom solution`,`display tag`, all dependents upon your use case,better describe your problem completely

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on your goals and data you want to display. Answer questions like:

- will you want to export to PDF/Excel?
- Will you display large data sets or small ones?
- will you need to perform asynchronous requests?

Datatable seems like an interesting solution, albeit completely javascript based.
I have mostly used displaytag and it's easy to use. However, the project seems abandoned so no updates are expected (I've recently forked it to https://github.com/mmalmeida/displaytag/ so we can fix the existing issues).

[JMesa](http://code.google.com/p/jmesa/) is also quite good. It's a bit harder to implement it cleanly (ie, without creating unwanted dependencies) - so I'd consider using it only for intermediate developers.

Answer (score 0):

A good could be use [Displaytag](http://www.displaytag.org), works fine with struts2 and uses a jsp like tags. Also you could export the results (in pdf or excel) use pagination, order the rows based on the columns order etc....